Spin connection definition/formula
After defining spin structures and spinor bundles on a given vector bundle, my professor defined a spin connection as a connection on the spin bundle given by the formula
$\tilde{\Gamma}_{\mu}^{ij} \, dx^{\mu} \otimes e_i e_j = \frac{1}{4} \left( e_{\nu}^{i} \Gamma_{\mu \sigma}^{\nu} e^{\sigma j} + e_{\nu}^{i} \partial_{\mu} e^{\nu j} \right) dx^{\mu} \otimes e_i e_j$
I'm really confused about this. First of all, there is a Christoffel symbol on the LHS, but we're looking for a principal connection; maybe the professor mistyped and meant a connection on the spinor bundle instead? Supposing that's what happened, I still don't understand where this formula comes from. I don't even understand what $e_i e_j$ and $e^{\sigma j}$ are.
Let's start from what I think I know: given a metric covariant derivative on the original vector bundle, it can be proved that it induces a principal connection on the SO structure, which in turns induces a principal connection on the spin structure via the pullback given by the double cover. Now, this principal connection induce a covariant derivative on the spinor bundle via the spinor representation of the Spin group. Calling $\rho$ this representation, $\hat{\rho}$ the representation of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{spin}$ it induces, $r$ the double cover of the spin structure, $\Gamma$ the Christoffel symbol of the original vector bundle E, $\tilde{\Gamma}$ the one of the spinor bundle S, $e^j_i$ a basis of $\mathfrak{gl}(E_x)$ and $\tilde{e}^j_i$ a basis of $\mathfrak{gl}(S_x)$, I would then write
$\tilde{\Gamma}^i_{j k} \ \tilde{e}^j_i \otimes dx^k = \hat{\rho} (r^* (\Gamma^l_{m n} \ e^m_l \otimes dx^n))$.
I don't know how to proceed from here since we don't have the explicit forms of $\rho$ and $r$.
I understand I may not expressed myself correctly (as my first language is not English) or that I may have written some nonsense (as my background is not in pure math). So feel free to ask for clarifications in the comments.
Edit: I think I'm almost there, also thanks to some suggestions from Quaere Verum. 
Start by noticing that $r$ acts as a conjugation so $r_*: \mathfrak{spin} \to \mathfrak{so}$ acts as a commutator. This means that
$$A^{i j} e_i e_j \mapsto A^{i j} (e_i e_j - e_j e_i) = 2 A^{i j} e_i e_j$$
The induced connection on the spinor bundle is then $$\bar{\Gamma}^{i j} _\mu \  dx^\mu \otimes \rho(e_i e_j) = \frac{1}{2} \Gamma^{i j} _\mu \ dx^\mu \otimes e_i e_j$$
With an abuse of notation, understanding that Cl acts on the spinors via $\rho$, we can write
$$\bar{\Gamma}^{i j} _\mu \  dx^\mu \otimes e_i e_j = \frac{1}{2} \Gamma^{i j} _\mu \ dx^\mu \otimes e_i e_j$$
Now, if we express it in a basis of sections of the spinor bundle $\{\tilde{e}_i\}$, we can use
$$ \nabla _i X = \partial_i X + \bar{\Gamma}^j_{i k} X^k e_i$$
to get
$$\tilde{\Gamma}^i_{\mu k} = (\nabla_{\mu} \tilde{e}_k)^i = (\partial _\mu \tilde{e}_k^\sigma + \bar{\Gamma}^\sigma _{\mu \nu} \tilde{e}_k ^\nu ) e_\sigma ^i = (\partial _\mu \tilde{e}_k^\sigma + \frac{1}{2}  \Gamma^\sigma _{\mu \nu} \tilde{e}_k ^\nu ) e_\sigma ^i $$
where $e_\sigma ^i$ are the components of $\{e^i\}$ in the basis $\{\tilde{e}^i\}$.
This formula is quite close to the one written down by my professor, if we identify a few symbols with each other. However I may very possibly have got wrong what the symbols or the process were, so please tell me what you think.\ Supposing for a moment I got it right, there are two differences. The first one is that the multiplicative constant is in front of both terms in his equation. I may have got something wrong or he could have made a little mistake, as many have already happened during this course. The other one is that I got $\frac{1}{2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{4}$. This is quite strange for me because this constant seems arbitrary since it comes from the isomorphism $\mathfrak{spin} \cong \mathfrak{so}$. I did what I thought was a natural choice, which was using $r^*$, but I suspect it can be done arbitrarily.

I refer to this article: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Christoffel+symbols for an explanation as to why I prefer staying away from the "yoga" of handling indices. In my answer below, a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ is introduced due to summing over all pairs $(i,j)$, instead of just the pairs $i>j$ as would be typical since $\omega$ is skew-symmetric. Another factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from the the embedding of $\mathfrak{so}(V)$. That's where the factor of $\frac{1}{4}$ comes from in my derivation.

The page you linked is interesting, and shows a dual way to compute this expression, choosing a basis on the spin bundle instead of the associated spinor bundle. It is also useful because seems that my process was right, can you confirm? For what concerns the multiplication factor, since we transform $\Gamma$ to $\omega$, the matrix should already be summing over all the indices. In any case, at the end we reconvert $\bar{\omega}$ to $\bar{\Gamma}$ so the choice of the summation should make no difference I suppose.

If you'll allow a digression, I'll first define the spin connection in a coordinate free manner. I find this to be enlightening. Recall that a connection $\nabla$ on a vector bundle $E\to M$ is a map  $\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(M,E\otimes T^*M)$ which satisfies the Leibniz rule. Locally, we can write $\nabla=d+A$ for some $1$-form $A$, and any collection of $1$-form satisfying some transformation rules define a linear connection. Now suppose that $(E\to M, g)$ is a spinnable vector bundle together with a quadratic form. A connection $\nabla$ on $E$ induces a principal connection $\omega$ on $\text{Fr}(E)$ which pulls back to a principal connection $\omega_S$ on $S(E)$, the spin bundle of $E$. You noted this yourself already.
Now, for any principal $G$-bundle $P\to M$ and representation $\rho:G\to\text{GL}(V)$, it is true that a principal connection $\omega$ on $P$ induces a covariant derivative $\nabla$ on $E_\rho = P\times_\rho V$, the associated bundle, and this connection is defined locally as $\nabla_Xs = ds(X) + \rho(\omega(X))s$ where $\rho$ is the induced representation at the level of Lie algebras, i.e. $\rho:\mathfrak{g}\to\text{End}(V)$. That is to say, the spin connection is defined by its local $1$-form, so one should check that this is well-defined etc. So this is basically what you seemingly wanted to write down, in a coordinate free way.
Now how is this expressed locally? Recall that $\text{Cl}(s,t)$ contains $\mathfrak{so}(V)$ as a Lie sub-algebra via $\varphi:\mathfrak{so}(V)\to\text{Cl}(s,t)$ defined by $\varphi(u\wedge v)=\frac{1}{4}(uv-vu)$. Here the isomorphism $\mathfrak{so}(V)\cong\wedge^2V$ is used. Now, equipped with this information, the local $1$-form $\rho(\omega)$ w.r.t. a local orthonormal frame $\{e^i\}$ becomes
\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j}\frac{1}{2}\omega_{ij}\otimes \varphi(e^i\otimes e_j)=\sum_{i,j}\frac{1}{2}\omega_{ij}\otimes \frac{1}{4}(e^ie^j-e^je^i)=\sum_{i,j}\frac{1}{4}\omega_{ij}\otimes e^ie^j
\end{align}
When translated to Cristoffel symbols, this becomes the formula written down by your professor. Note that $\omega(X)\in\mathfrak{spin}(s,t)$ and $\rho(\omega(X))\in\text{Cl}(s,t)\subseteq\text{End}(V)$. We were able to use $\mathfrak{so}(V)$ because $\{e_i\}$ is chosen to be a local orthonormal frame.

Thank you for your answer. I tried to work the rest out and edited my original question to add what I think I may have figured out.
